# How to indicate a columns as NOT NULL in a view?

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, entities

I'm trying to use a view to create an ADO.NET entity using a view. However, that view does not have a single column that is NOT NULL.

One thing that occurred to me was to create a NOT NULL column on the view to use as a 'primary key' for the view. This worked, but the field is still reported as NULL.

Is there a way to force or trick SQL Server to report that view column as NOT NULL?

Imagine the view as something like:

```
CREATE VIEW vwSample WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ID = convert(uniqueidentifier, /* some computed value */)
      ,Field1
      ,Field2
      ,Field3
  FROM tbSample
```

> **Note:** *Before saying that I can edit the entity XML to do such thing, I'm asking this because I have a **VERY** large number of entities to be created this way.*

Comment: do you want to add sequential primary key to your view?

Comment: If the data is not naturally identifiable then why would you want to add a primary key to it? I doubt you'd want to join using this fake primary key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's worth the effort, but I think creating a function that returns Temporary Table with NOT NULL fields should work for the computed value. ex.

```
Create function fnSTestample()
returns @Test TABLE 
(
    tableId varchar(100) not null
)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
as
begin
    insert @Test(tableID)
    select 'some computed value' from dbo.someTable
return
end
```

and then you select that function in the view.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, to answer your question:

You don't want to use `newid()` to determine your id field, since this will be recalculated every time you use the view. Really, data integrity is the biggest issue.

```
select
    row_number() over (order by someStaticAndUniqueFieldLikeCreateDate) as ID,
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3
from
    tblA
order by
    someStaticAndUniqueFieldLikeCreateDate
```

This only works if you're ordering on a field that will have a consistent ordering that will append new rows, such as a `CreateDate` field. If you don't have this, that ID is subject to change. Now, if you only need these ID's at runtime, and there's nothing that permanently links to them, `row_number` will be just peachy keen. If you have unreliable data, there's no way to have a reliable ID field *unless* you create an additional table and use triggers to populate it.

Secondly, be careful with that `with schemabinding`. It's dangerous if used as a kludge. Remember that as soon as you create a view `with schemabinding`, you cannot alter the schema of *any* underlying table *at all*. This means you can't make a `varchar(50)` column a `varchar(100)` without dropping and re-adding all views that have `with schemabinding` enabled. Yes, you can index a view that's schemabound, but there are definitely tradeoffs that need to get taken into account before you go lock, stock, and barrel.

Answer (score 1):

I used `ISNULL` for this. I.e. something like the following worked for me:

```
CREATE VIEW vwSample WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ID = ISNULL(uniqueidentifier, /*some computed value */)
      ,Field1
      ,Field2
      ,Field3
  FROM tbSample
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [newid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276822(SQL.80).aspx)

```
CREATE VIEW vwSample WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT ID = NEWID()
      ,Field1
      ,Field2
      ,Field3
  FROM tbSample
```